# mysql permissions issue - associated with my.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql permissions issue - associated with my.cnf](https://serverfault.com/questions/301040/mysql-permissions-issue-associated-with-my-cnf)

I want to change the max_allowed_packet value, but when setting permissions for my.cnf to 777, I get (as expected):

**Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/my.cnf' is ignored**

If I set it to anything less than that (600, 644, 700, 775, all tried...), the mysqld service fails to start.

The error log when the service fails to restart is:

> 110814 14:30:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql    958 Warning: World-writable config file
>   '/etc/my.cnf' is ignored    959 110814 14:30:28 [Note] Plugin
>   'ndbcluster' is disabled.    960 /usr/libexec/mysqld: Table
>   'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist    961 110814 14:30:28 [ERROR] Can't open
>   the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.    962
>   110814 14:30:28  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M    963
>   110814 14:30:28  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>   964 110814 14:30:28  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 47678
>   965 110814 14:30:28 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables:
>   Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist    966 110814 14:30:28 [ERROR]
>   Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 20. Created with
>   MySQL 50086, now running 50158. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this
>   error.    967 110814 14:30:28 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv`
>   column at position 29    968 110814 14:30:28 [ERROR] Cannot open
>   mysql.event    969 110814 14:30:28 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error
>   occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event
>   Scheduler.    970 110814 14:30:28 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready
>   for connections.    971 Version: '5.1.58'  socket:
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution    972
>   110814 14:33:46 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown    973
>   974 110814 14:33:46  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...    975 110814
>   14:33:48  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 47678
>   976 110814 14:33:48 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>   977     978 110814 14:33:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file
>   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

Being a newbie to linux, I do not understand much of this error log, but it may make sense to some of you.

I believe this has to do with the permissions set to some files, as I found many files being set to 777. I don't know much, but I know that's bad. :)
Thing is though, I don't know where to start looking and fixing.

The system all this is done on is CentOS 5.5.

**EDIT: This has finally gotten solved. It was achieved by changing the bind-address inside my.cnf from the actual IP to 127.0.0.1 . Thank you all for your help.**
Also, there is duplicate of this question, because I didn't know it could be moved from one forum to the other. Feel free to delete this one, or the other one (has the exact same title).

Answer (score 3):

**Never** chmod any files to 777. It means that everyone can write to your file.

`my.cnf` should has permission 644 and owned by root. About the error *"Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist"*, as it said, you should created a `~/.my.cnf` file in $HOME as belows:

```
[mysql_upgrade]
user     = user
password = password
socket   = /path/to/mysql.sock
```

and run [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html) to fix that.